# Insert custom element at the bottom of an ActiveAdmin index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to insert a custom element at the bottom of an ActiveAdmin index page. For example, having a `Campaign` model, in the ActiveAdmin campaign index page I would like to have the default index table followed by my custom element (a partial named `campaigns_custom_element`). 
I tried with the following code:

```
index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :name
    column :advertiser
    column :duration
    column :paused
    column :in_preparation

    panel 'A custom panel' do
      render partial: 'campaigns_custom_element'
    end
  end
```

The problem is that ActiveAdmin always places the index table as last element:

[image]

Instead, my desired layout would be the index table followed by my custom element:

[image]

There is an easy and clean way to do this without having to create a whole custom index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If relying on javascript does not bother you here's a little proof of concept: Wrap your panel in div like so:

```
div(id: 'get_lower') do
  panel 'A custom panel' do
    render partial: 'campaigns_custom_element'
  end
end
```

Then add this snippet at then end of app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js

```
;(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#get_lower").insertAfter(".index_table");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is perfect. One could also add the JS snippet directly inside a `script`  tag in the `html.erb` file containing the partial.